# Why this simple Scala for comprehension does not execute the futures?

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I'm stuck figuring out why this does not work:

```
import scala.concurrent.future
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val result1 = future("a")
    val result2 = future("b")
    val result3 = future("c")

    val res = for {
      r1 <- result1
      r2 <- result2
      r3 <- result3
    } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)

    for { r <- res} yield(println(r))
  }
}
```

I'm expecting this to print "abc", but nothing really happens.

Comment: Prints "abc" in my case...

Comment: I fixed this adding an Await.result(res, 3 minutes) where res is a val assigned from the for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are executing a stand alone program and the problem is that the main thread is terminated before the future can complete, to see something you could use this:

```
import scala.concurrent.future
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val result1 = future("a")
    val result2 = future("b")
    val result3 = future("c")

    val res = for {
      r1 <- result1
      r2 <- result2
      r3 <- result3
    } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)

    val printing = for { r <- res} yield(println(r))

    Await.ready(printing, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Comment: Somehow I expected the program to automatically wait indefinitely for futures to terminate. Apparently this does not happen. I found a similar solution just before your answer (see second comment to question). However yes, I agree this is the solution.

Comment: Well, if that was the case there would be probably no use for futures since the main thread could block indefinitely waiting for a future result :D

Comment: I agree Futures should be async in general, but at least the main thread COULD wait the any unfinished futures before termination. I guess!

Comment: @sscarduzio This is more about the ExecutionContext than Futures. You can supply your own ExecutionContext that uses non-daemon threads.